# How to tune Informix database performance

Tags: performance, informix

I want to how to do following general step:

1. where to find slow SQL
2. how to debug SQL (including functions)
3. how to create index properly
4. when using "update statistics", when should I use HIGH or LOW, and why?

I am going to write a paper about this topic; any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One place to start is, funnily enough, the [Informix Performance Tuning Guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.perf.doc/perf.htm), one section of the [Informix 11.70 Information Centre](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp).  In particular, it explains most of what you need to know about UPDATE STATISTICS, and also about automatic update statistics.

For question 3, at one level, there isn't much to it - you follow the syntax from the manuals and it works.  I'm guessing though that you're more concerned with whether you should create an index on a table; this would in part follow on from questions 1 and 2.

There are a variety of ways to find slow SQL.  If you have [OAT](http://www.openadmintool.org/) (OpenAdmin Tool), then it has ways to report the slowest queries.  Alternatively, you can look to SET EXPLAIN.

If you have Informix 11.70, then there is a built-in SPL (stored procedure language) debugging facility.  For earlier versions, [Server Studio and Sentinel](http://www.serverstudio.com/) has some support.  You can also look at the built-in TRACE facility and the related SET DEBUG FILE statement, but they tend to be tricky to interpret, and don't really give you performance information (more a question of correct vs incorrect functioning).

Comment: 《Informix Performance Tuning Guide》 this is what I am looking for